# Stream of optional fields return values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a few Optional fields with String and Long values:

```
Optional<Long> id;
Optional<String> name;
Optional<String> lastname;
Optional<Long> number;
....
```

I would like to return List with contains all of the values. If e.g optional "name" is no present, should be stored empty String. Result of method should be List with values e.q: "1", "John", "", "5".

I made stream:

```
Stream fields = Stream.of(id, name, lastname, number);
```

But I have no idea what next.

Regards.

Comment: I would like to return List<String> with contains all of the values. If  e.g optional "name" is no present, should be stored empty String. Result of method should be List with values e.q: "1", "John", "", "5".

Comment: You should edit your question with this additional information.

Comment: That’s why using `Optional` for fields is discouraged. Why not declare all fields as plain `String` and initialize them with empty strings in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
List<String> list = Stream.of(id, name, lastname, number)
        .map(op -> op.map(o -> o.toString()).orElse(""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On each optional in stream you will map it into it's `String` version using `toString()` from `Object` class and for `null` you will map it into empty `String`. Than, you will collect it into list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method of the stream to manipulate the content of your stream, something like the below code:

```
fields.map(field -> field.orElse("").toString());
```

The optional also has a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method that can be used when manipulating the stream:

```
fields.map(field -> field.map(x -> x.toString()).orElse(""));
```

Comment: Yes, it will, the only change that is needed is to put the parameter in the `Stream`, making it `Stream<Optional> fields ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> ls = Stream.of(a, b).filter(o -> o != null && !o.trim().equals("")).map(o -> o instanceof Long ? String.valueOf(o) : o).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

1. Create a stream
2. Add a filter which will keep the values if two condition are respected: they are not null and if it is true the string value is not empty (the trim() method permits to remove the empty chars which are on the left and the right of the value)
3. Use a map method in order to transform objects which are Long instances into String instances
4. Use a collect method in order to retrieve values

Comment: @TobySpeight i did it.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
List<String> result = fields.map(o -> o.orElse(""))  // provide default value
                            .map(o -> o.toString())  // cast to String
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect into List
```

[See it in action](https://ideone.com/rBYYKH).

Comment: It works only if you have `Optional` without type. In question we see that his optionals are parametrized.

Comment: @ByeBye seems to work fine with parametrized optionals, unless I missed something ; please check my updated ideone.

Comment: @ByeBye as long as the `Stream` is a `Stream` of unparametrized `Optional` (which accepts any `Optional<T>`), the first map casts from unparametrized `Optional` to `Object` (which includes `String`), then the second casts from `Object` to `String`.

Comment: It make sense, but for this you have to extract variable with stream.

Comment: @ByeBye yeah, which was OP's context ;)